# How to manage different config files for development and production with react-native

Tags: react-native

For testing my app locally I put dummy values in the code. Several times, I have forgotten to remove these values and pushed the changes, which is fine in development, but not in production. To avoid that this happens, I wanted to have a local config that overwrites the global config file. Something like :

```
const config = {
  'auth.initial.email': '',
  'auth.initial.password': '',
}

// Override defaults with local config
let extraConfig = null
try {
  extraConfig = require('./config.local')
} catch(err) {}

Object.assign(config, extraConfig.default)
export default config
```

I believe this would work in node, but in react-native I get an error "Unable to resolve module". Is there a standard solution for this, or a simple way to catch and ignore import errors from JS in react-native?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `__DEV__` variable from react-native.

This variable is set to `true` if you are in development mode.

It's set to `false` if your app is in production.

Comment: yes, this kind of works, but it means that I have to push also dev config to repo. Cause even wrapped in a `if` block `require` will fail if file doesnt exist

Comment: You could use following package for that: [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)